# Opening up a CLI version of my code from within window form in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I've made a checkers game using both windows forms and a normal class program in c# and I can change between them by changing which is set as the startup project but I was wondering if it was possible to open up the CLI version of the checkers game which I did in the normal class program from within the windows form as it's running. If this is possible, may I please see how to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Process.Start` to start the CLI version:

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = // the path to the bin\Debug folder where your executable exists
processStartInfo.FileName = // the name of your executable (including .exe)
Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

Comment: `var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory@"C:\Users\'username'\source\repos\Computing - Project\Computing Project\bin\Debug";
processStartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\username\source\repos\Computing - Project\Computing Project\bin\Debug\Computing Project.exe";
Process.Start(processStartInfo); `  This is what i put it down in my code but it doesn't seem to work and returns the error "The system cannot find the file specified File". how do i fix this?

Comment: Nevermind I figured out it was the spaces between the first computing and project.